# regex global match with append

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex, which would help to match sequence of symbol `}` and append string before it.
Here's the example text that I want to substitute:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){#oaw {color: #ccc} #oaw .oa-form form button{width:100%}}
```

Should become:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){#oaw {color: #ccc !important} .oa-form form button{width:100% !important}}
```

I want to match every occurrence of `}+` and replace it with `!important}+` so that the following replacements would be done:

```
} -> !important}
}} -> !important}}
and so on..
```

Is there any way that I could tell regex to match `}+` and append `!important` before it (replace it with custom string and append matched string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with matching:

```
(} *}?)
```

and replacing with

```
 !important $1
```